# iOS today widget only shows up while debugging

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, widget, ios8-today-widget

I am developing an app with swift using a today widget for notification center.

The widget works:

- when using the simulator
- when starting the widget separately using xcode

The widget does not work when starting the main app using xcode on my iPhone 6. It appears but is empty, only showing the header and title without content.

I read that the architecture selected could be a problem but everything looks fine. My widget build settings:
[image: My widget build settings]
I already tried making a clean build and deleting the app completely before running a new build. Nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself. The Layout was the problem. 
Disabled "Autoresize Subviews" of my imageView I used in the Widget.

Works now